# Trying to make a simple Sql query in PHP

Tags: php, mysql

Hello can you help me with this script?

Im trying to pull information on my slider from database.

```
$query = "SELECT * FROM `slider1`";
$select_from_slider1 = mysqli_query($connection, $query);
while ($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($select_from_slider1)){
    $slider1_title = $row['slider1_title'];
    $slider1_content = $row['slider1_content'];
    $slider1_moreinfo = $row['slider1_moreinfo'];
    ?>
    <h2><?php echo $slider1_title ?></h2>
    <p><?php echo $slider1_content ?></p>
    <?php echo $slider1_moreinfo ?>
<?php } ?>
```

This is the error i get:
[image]

Lol im sorry i figured it out myself, the reason for the error was that i dublicated many times include "database"....
Thanks guys for the fast replies.!

Comment: Check where you define `$connection`, doesn't look like its defined anywhere. Maybe you forgot to include the connection, or named the connection something other than `$connection`?

Comment: ^^ Or you are calling this code in a function in which `$connection` is not in scope (was defined outside the function)

Comment: You don't define $connection, so it's undefined;)

Comment: You should use PDO rather than mysqli.

Comment: @MaximeFlament That's rather opinionated - The MySQLi API supports prepared statement too, and its still a good, perfectly valid API to use, *if you want* to use it, there's nothing wrong about it.

Comment: No it's not. mysqli's prepared statements are impossible on client side. Furthermore, PDO supports way more databases drivers than mysqli. For example, see: https://code.tutsplus.com/tutorials/pdo-vs-mysqli-which-should-you-use--net-24059

Comment: Yes, it *is* opinionated. If you like it - fine, but there's no need to force your choice upon others, if their choice works for them. Its rare to suddenly change your database driver out of the blue, and MySQLi has features which PDO doesn't. http://php.net/manual/en/mysqlinfo.api.choosing.php - There's nothing wrong with using `mysqli_*` if you want to - I personally like PDO better, but `mysqli_*` is just as valid as PDO.

Comment: I solved it thanks guys!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Looks like the var $connection isn't a mysqli connection. You'll need the following somewhere this script can access it.

```
$connection = mysqli_connect('localhost', 'my_user', 'my_password', 'my_db');
```

http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.construct.php

Comment: $db['db_host'] = "****";
$db['db_user'] = "****";
$db['db_pass'] = "****";
$db['db_name'] = "*****";

foreach ($db as $key => $value) {
    define(strtoupper($key), $value);

}

$connection = mysqli_connect(DB_HOST, DB_USER, DB_PASS, DB_NAME);
if($connection){
    //echo "connected"; im using this script

Comment: Sure, is this file included? Just do a simple test like create '$test = 5;' and see if you can echo $test in the file you are running the query from. If you can't echo 5 then you know it's an include problem, if you can echo 5 then there's probably an issue with the connection its self, like wrong password, no access to the db, etc. If there is a connection error you can access this with http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.error.php

Comment: It was the include "database.php" yep! thanks i solved it